# BO 4.1: How to capture the changes in a report data?

Tags: sdk, business-intelligence, business-objects

I need to create a report in any technology, that will show the difference
in data between the same report executed week earlier.

Ideally the look and feel would be similar to that of a changes marking in MS Word.

Please share your insights.

With the datasource:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Could you update your question with the version of BusinessObjects you're using and the data source?

Comment: BO version is 4.1 and datasource is Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to opt for Web Intelligence, and depending on the version of BusinessObjects you're using, there's the *Track Changes* feature which will do exactly what you're looking for.

You have the option of comparing data against the previous refresh or a fixed point in time. Have a look at the tutorial [Track changes to data](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21147) for a short introduction. This feature is also described in WebI's help files and documentation (available at [help.sap.com](http://help.sap.com))

Below is a screenshot of the track changes configuration dialog.
[image]

Comment: This was applied and gives erroneus results so I will need some other approach. A custom one probably.